# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function error , when passing store with provider in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

[image]

I am new to React JS and redux . i am facing issue when importing store component into index.js .
    i have uploaded screen shots for reference.
    Please help.

```
Code :
import {applyMiddleware,combineReducers,createStore} from 'react';
import numberReducer from '../app/reducers/numberReducer';
import nameReducer from '../app/reducers/nameReducer';
import  logger from 'redux-logger';

export default  createStore(combineReducers({
    name:nameReducer , 
    number:numberReducer
}),
{},
applyMiddleware(logger())
);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include the error message(s) as text rather than as an image, to make it easier for people to help you. Thank you.

Comment: You need to share store file code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {applyMiddleware,combineReducers,createStore} from 'react';
```

Is this your actual code? These should be imported from `redux`, not `react`.